# How to use OCMock to verify that an asynchronous method does not get called in Objective C?

Tags: objective-c, xcode, unit-testing, asynchronous, ocmock

I want to verify that a function is **not** called. The function is executed in an asynchronous block call inside the tested function and therefore `OCMReject()` does not work.

The way I have tested if async functions are indeed called would be as follows:

```
id mock = OCMClassMock([SomeClass class]);
OCMExpect([mock methodThatShouoldExecute]);
OCMVerifyAllWithDelay(mock, 1);
```

How would a test be done to test if a forbidden function is not called?
Something like:

```
VerifyNotCalled([mock methodThatShouoldExecute]);
OCMVerifyAllWithDelay(mock, 1);
```

Answer (score 3, accepted):

I would recommend using an `OCMStrictClassMock` instead of the `OCMClassMock` (which gives you a nice mock). A strict mock will instantly fail your test if any method is called on it that you did not stub or expect, which makes your tests a lot more rigorous.

If that's not an option for you, you can do what you described with:

```
OCMReject([mock methodThatShouoldExecute]);
```

See the "Failing fast for regular (nice) mocks" section in the [OCMock docs](http://ocmock.org/reference/).

Now as for waiting for your code which *may* call the forbidden method, that's another matter. You can't use `OCMVerifyAllWithDelay` since that returns immediately as soon as all expectations are met, it doesn't wait around a full second to see if illegal calls will be made to it. One option is to put a 1 second wait before verifying the mock each time. Ideally, you could also wait explicitly on your asynchronous task with an [XCTestExpectation](https://developer.apple.com/documentation/xctest/xctestexpectation). Something like:

```
XCTestExpectation *asyncTaskCompleted = [self expectationWithDescription:@"asyncTask"];
// Enqueued, in an onCompletion block, or whatever call 
//  ... [asyncTaskCompleted fulfill]

[self waitForExpectationsWithTimeout:1 handler:nil]
```